# Elegant solution for a dynamic ng-repeat form

Tags: angularjs, forms, iterator, key, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and I have following problem:
I want to iterate over an array of 'attributes' with a bunch of keys for the values stored in the Object.

```
<div ng-repeat="key in attributes">
         {{key}}: <input type="text" value={{Object.key}} name="{{key}}">
</div>
```

This code displays just the correct key of {{column}} but delivers no result for the value of {{Object.column}}. 
The phrase {{Object.{{column}}}} dosn't work neither.

If I run the code, giving the Object a static key of (e.g. ID) everything works perfectly.

I could go for

```
<div>
     id: <input type="text" value={{Object.id}} name="id">
     name: <input type="text" value={{Object.name}} name="name">
     value: <input type="text" value={{Object.value}} name="value">
     and so on...
</div>
```

But this static form does not seem to be the perfect solution.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly ;)

Comment: Thing to remember with the `{{ }}` syntax is that the stuff inside it is just a normal JavaScript expression that gets evaluated - the syntax inside the braces will be the same as if you were just doing it in normal code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like this -

```
<div ng-repeat="key in attributes">
    {{key}}: <input type="text" value={{ Object[key] }} name="{{ Object[key] }}">
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome and please accept my answer if it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Use `{{Object[key]}}`. Angular considers .key to be a constant not a variable.